# Function call dataBinding change in react

Tags: reactjs

I want to replace "Hello!" with "hi". The following is what I've tried, however it does not work for me:

```
<script type="text/jsx">
    var Input = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
      return {value: 'Hello!'};
    },
    handleChange: function(event) {
      this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    },
    render: function () {
      var value = this.state.value;
      return (
        <div>
          <input type="text" value={value} onChange={this.handleChange} id="test1" disabled/>
          <p>{value}</p>
        </div>
      );
    }
  });

  React.render(<Input/>, document.body);        
</script>

<script>
function test(){
   $("#test1").value = "hi";
}

test();
</script>
```

I can not function in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Your input has the Id `test1` not `test`

```
function test(){
   $("#test1").val("hi");
}
```

This is the problem I saw in your code still not sure what you are looking for as this is not thew ReactJs was way of doing things